# Replace variables during parsing - pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

Suppose I have somewhat of a simplified expression as follows

```
(3 + 7 + (x + 5))
```

Is there a way using pyparsing that I can evaluate the expression and during the runtime notice x is a variable that needs to be replaced by the outer expression?
So basically 3+7 gets evaluated to 10, x is a variable that gets replaced by 10 so the final expression would be

```
(3 + 7 + (10 + 5))
```

had I known x was 10 before runtime.

The variable will always have a 'parent' above it for replace. I'm really not sure where to start looking.

I guess my questions are:

1. Does pyparsing allow for something like this?
2. If not is there a parsing library in python that does?
3. Am I better off building my own parser for this problem where I could implement a peek() or next() method to allow me handle this as I recurse

Any hints or documentation to get started would be great.

**EDIT:**
Sorry if I lead people in the wrong direction or caused confusion my trying to oversimplify my question. I'll try to expand more but it get's complicated as there would be quite a bit of coding behind it.

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
prices_by_day = {
  'monday' : [
    {'name' : 'apple', 'price' : 0.99},
    {'name' : 'orange', 'price': 1.99}
  ],
  'tuesday': [
    {'name' : 'apple', 'price' : 0.50},
    {'name' : 'orange', 'price': 0.80}
  ]
}
```

What I want to be able to do is write an expression to get the price for apples on monday take that price and find all items that are less than that price for tuesday.
The problem is that I won't always know the price of apples on monday or the price may change, but I want to be able to pass that down into an expression once I know
for something like

```
 get(price of apples monday) and 
 get(price of all tuesday array objects < ${PREVIOUSLY_EVALUAED_PRICE_OF_APPLES})
```

I hope this helped explain more and didn't make it more confusing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954340/change-string-during-pyparsing

Comment: I did read that article previously, but what was missing for me in that article was how to pass the variable down. i.e. 3+7 which equals 10 to x. Is that something that can/should be stored in a parser interface class?

Comment: @badger0053 I don't understand your math. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I used a math example to try and simply explain what I want to do. I guess I failed at that. What I'm intending is that 3+7 as well as X will actually evaluate to a dictionary. I want to take values from "3+7" and pass those down into "X". Sorry if mislead anybody with my question.

Comment: I think the confusing part here is that your expression doesn't really tell us your logic for how the parser should know to assign the sum of 3 and 7 to 'x' before proceeding. It *is* possible with pyparsing to do this kind of parse-time evaluation and substitution, but your assignment strategy needs a bit more description in order to get anything more than a solution that is specific to just this example.

Comment: So you are just trying avoid repeating the apple price expression? Is `get(price of all tuesday array objects < get(price of apples monday))` so bad? The thing is, it will very dodgy to just take whatever price was previously evaluated, given things like precedence of operations.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I feel a little silly now. Yes, that will work. I was stuck in the mindset of trying to not re-process things already calculated and wasn't really thinking of the actual problem at hand. I can refactor and make things work. Thank You!